# Document Analysis and Tagging

Tags: nlp, tagging, classification, bayesian

Let's say I have a bunch of essays (thousands) that I want to tag, categorize, etc.  Ideally, I'd like to train *something* by manually categorizing/tagging a few hundred, and then let the thing loose.

What resources (books, blogs, languages) would you recommend for undertaking such a task?  Part of me thinks this would be a good fit for a [Bayesian Classifier](http://www.process.com/precisemail/bayesian_filtering.htm) or even [Latent Semantic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis), but I'm not really familiar with either other than what I've found from a few [ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/bishop/) [gems](http://classifier.rubyforge.org/).

Can something like this be solved by a bayesian classifier?  Should I be looking more at semantic analysis/natural language processing?  Or, should I just be looking for keyword density and mapping from there?

Any suggestions are appreciated (I don't mind picking up a few books, if that's what's needed)!

Comment: In this area, NLP is mostly useful for 'tokenizing' - i.e. cutting input documents into individual words. However a naive approach (words are letters, everything else is whitespace) is usually good enough for classification, so I wouldn't bother with that too much. For everything else, please see answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, that's a pretty huge topic you are venturing into :)
There is definitely a lot of books and articles you can read about it but I will try to provide a short introduction. I am not a big expert but I worked on some of this stuff.

First you need to decide whether you are want to classify essays into predefined topics/categories (classification problem) or you want the algorithm to decide on different groups on its own (clustering problem). From your description it appears you are interested in classification.

Now, when doing classification, you first need to create enough training data. You need to have a number of essays that are separated into different groups. For example 5 physics essays, 5 chemistry essays, 5 programming essays and so on. Generally you want as much training data as possible but how much is enough depends on specific algorithms. You also need verification data, which is basically similar to training data but completely separate. This data will be used to judge quality (or performance in math-speak) of your algorithm.

Finally, the algorithms themselves. The two I am familiar with are Bayes-based and TF-IDF based. For Bayes, I am currently developing something similar for myself in ruby, and I've documented my experiences in my blog. If you are interested, just read this - http://arubyguy.com/2011/03/03/bayes-classification-update/ and if you have any follow up questions I will try to answer.

The TF-IDF is a short for TermFrequence - InverseDocumentFrequency. Basically the idea is for any given document to find a number of documents in training set that are most similar to it, and then figure out it's category based on that. For example if document D is similar to T1 which is physics and T2 which is physics and T3 which is chemistry, you guess that D is most likely about physics and a little chemistry.

The way it's done is you apply the most importance to rare words and no importance to common words. For instance 'nuclei' is rare physics word, but 'work' is very common non-interesting word. (That's why it's called inverse term frequency). If you can work with Java, there is a very very good Lucene library which provides most of this stuff out of the box. Look for API for 'similar documents' and look into how it is implemented. Or just google for 'TF-IDF' if you want to implement your own

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I'll start diving into some of those links today.  For classification (which is more what I'm interested in at the moment), do both the Bayes-based and TF-IDF based algorithms allow for classification into multiple categories, or are they more targeted toward identifying *one* predominant category?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes, both approaches allow for multiple categories. in fact, with both you get an ordered list of categories with score attached. it's up to you to select first n categories, or categories above threshold or any other approach

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past (though it was for short news articles) using some vector-cluster algorithm. I don't remember it right now, it was what Google used in its infancy.
Using their paper I was able to have a prototype running in PHP in one or two days, then I ported it to Java for speed purposes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model

http://www.la2600.org/talks/files/20040102/Vector_Space_Search_Engine_Theory.pdf